# python get previous day date in UTC using datetime(datetime.date) and timedelta

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

i wanted to get previous day date in UTC .

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
month_now = str(datetime.date(datetime.utcnow()))[:-3]
```

```
>>> print(month_now)
2021-01
```

And now

```
previous_day = str(datetime.date(datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)))
```

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Please help.All related posts was suggesting some thing like but need something with datetime.date

```
Previous_Date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) - be specific instead by using `timezone.utc`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

todayUTC = datetime.now(timezone.utc).date()
yesterdayUTC = today - timedelta(1)

print(todayUTC, yesterdayUTC)
# 2021-01-08 2021-01-07
```

Also not that classes `datetime`, `timedelta` etc. are classes from the datetime module. If you import them explicitly (`from datetime import ...`), you have to use them accordingly, hence the error. The other option is to import the module, so you can then call all its classes like e.g. `datetime.timedelta`, `datetime.datetime` and so on. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). Your original code then would have to look something like

```
import datetime

month_now = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().date())[:-3]
previous_day = str((datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date())
print(month_now, previous_day)
# 2021-01 2021-01-07
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But still unable to get using other option mentioned above, thought got the desired result I was looking to workout other option mentioned in comment

Comment: @div: I've added an example, maybe that helps to clarify.